# Spectogram of a .wav file returns wrong results

Tags: java

I am currently trying to plot the frequency domain of a .wav file which then i can use the values of, to train a neural network to predict which sound is playing.

I already read the bytes of the .wav file using this bit of code, starting from the 44th byte , which is the start of the data chunk:

```
entireFileData= Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath));
byte[] data_raw= Arrays.copyOfRange(entireFileData,44,entireFileData.length);

double[] dataNew=new double[(int)myDataSize/2];
int new_length=data_raw.length/2;
double val;

 myData = new byte[(int)myDataSize];
for(int i=0;i<new_length;i+=2) {
      val =((data_raw[i]*0xff)<<8)| (data_raw[i+1]*0xff);
      dataNew[i]=(double) val;
}
```

Then i used fourier transform on the byte array

```
ApacheFFT apacheFFT=new ApacheFFT();
apacheFFT.forward(dataNew,(float)44100,w);

Spectrum s = apacheFFT.getMagnitudeSpectrum(); //I used the getMagnitudeSpectrum method to be able to plot 
double[] freq=s.array();                       //the graph
double[] array=new double[freq.length]
```

Here is the createSpectrum method:

```
public static Spectrum createMagnitudeSpectrum(Complex[] data, float samplingrate, WindowFunction windowFunction) {
        int bins = data.length / 2;
        double normalizationFactor = data.length * windowFunction.normalization(data.length);

        double[] magnitudeSpectrum = new double[bins];
        magnitudeSpectrum[0] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(data[0].getReal(), 2) + Math.pow(data[0].getImaginary(), 2)) / normalizationFactor;
        for (int i = 1; i < bins; i++) {
            magnitudeSpectrum[i] = (2 * data[i].abs()) / normalizationFactor;
        }

        return new Spectrum(Type.MAGNITUDE, magnitudeSpectrum, FFTUtil.binCenterFrequencies(data.length, samplingrate));
    }
```

This is the Forward Fourier Transform i used, from the AppacheFFT package:

```
public void forward(double[] data, float samplingrate, WindowFunction window) {
        this.windowFunction = window;
        this.samplingrate = samplingrate;

        int actual_length = 8192;
        int valid_length = FFTUtil.nextPowerOf2(actual_length);
        double[] reshaped = new double[valid_length];
        for (int i = 0; i < reshaped.length; i++) {
            if (i < actual_length) {
                reshaped[i] = data[i] * this.windowFunction.value(i, valid_length);
            } else {
                reshaped[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        /* Perform FFT using FastFourierTransformer library. */
        FastFourierTransformer transformer = new FastFourierTransformer(DftNormalization.STANDARD);
        this.data = transformer.transform(reshaped, TransformType.FORWARD);

        /* Reset the calculated properties. */
        this.powerSpectrum = null;
        this.magnitudeSpectrum = null;
    }
```

I then plotted the values to a graph using LineGraphSeries like so:

```
for(int i=0;i<freq.length;i++)
    {
   dataPoints[i]=new DataPoint(i,freq[i]);
        
    }
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(dataPoints);
graph.addSeries(series);
```

So to test myself i used audacity's plot spectrum tool to see the difference, and it is quite a difference between my result and audacity's:

I am not allowed to post pictures so [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLfBT.png) a link to the comparison.

As you can see it's not even near the one in audacity. I have actually observed that my signal is mirrored from the half.

I tried multiple ways of reading the .wav file, multiple ways of plotting the file to the graph.
I can't really fathom what could have went wrong here.

Also i'm sorry if i made any formatting mistakes.

Any opinions on this?

Edit: Okay, i actually did it , it was the way i read the bytes, i didnt mask it, and bytes are signed so it would give me wrong values, but now it only works on one frequency, for example if i have a 3Khz sine wave file, it shows tehe 3Khz freq, if i have 10Khz it shows 10, but if i have both of the frequencies in one file, it only shows the 3Khz one

Comment: Time for some debugging on your end, first: generate a pure sine .wav of a single, known, frequency. What does your code do? Can you explain why it's doing what it's doing at each point, when you inspect the values for that single frequency in the methods that load and transform the signal?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i'll give it a try :)

Comment: Okay, i actually did it , it was the way i read the bytes, i didnt mask it, and bytes are signed so it would give me wrong values, but now it only works on one frequency, for example if i have a 3Khz sine wave file, it shows tehe 3Khz freq, if i have 10Khz it shows 10, but if i have both of the frequencies in one file, it only shows the 3Khz one

Comment: The you probably now have a different question, and it's time update your post (or close this one, and ask a new one if you want new eyes on it)